# TransitionDrawable with xml drawable - fading to xml drawable doesn't work properly

Tags: android, xml-drawable, transitiondrawable

I have a transition drawable fading from a png to an xml drawable (a simple gradient). When I call `startTransition(int time)` the image seems to fade strangely, leaving the previous drawable visible in the background, almost as if it only fades half way. It might be worth noting it seems to work without issue on lollipop (i've just seen this happen on kitkat phones I've tested so far).

Is there something I need to do to the xml drawable to make it function properly?

Answer (score 2):

Before calling `startTransition(int time)` try to invoke:

```
yourTransitionDrawable.setCrossFadeEnabled(true);
```

This seems to be necessary when you want a **real cross-fade** transition (and not a fade-in one).

Comment: I had actually tried that, and it does somewhat fade fully, but the end colour on the KitKat devices is not what the drawable should be (it appears as some faded grey colour), nothing like what appears if i just set the drawable straight onto the view